# Add one user and give it the same password for many servers

Tags: linux, bash, centos, redhat

I made a script to add one same user with one same password to many servers:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
password=`cat /root/scripts/password`
for i in `cat /root/scripts/LIST_TEST.txt`
do
        printf "Serveur : $i \n"
        ssh -tt -o PasswordAuthentication=no $i
        adduser newuser
        yes `echo $password` | passwd newuser
exit 0
done
```

Also I'm in root when using this script, it seems that the user is created but the password doesn't get changed, as I cannot login when I try ssh `newuser@server`.

What is bothering me is that when I manually log into the server as root, and do the command `` yes `echo $password` | passwd newuser `` and then logout and try again `newuser@server`, it works...

The script looks like this now it is a bit clearer but it still doesn't add the right password, I don't know what it gives as a new password...

```bash
#!/bin/bash
password=`cat /root/scripts/password`
for i in `cat /root/scripts/LIST_TEST.txt`
do
        printf "Serveur : $i \n"
        ssh $i 'adduser newuser; yes $password | passwd newuser'
        echo $password
done
```

Comment: Are you trying to ssh into the server and then keep running the commands of the same script? Because this can't happen like that. What is your goal run the script from your computer to the server, or you could move the script to the server and excecute it from there?

Comment: I have a list of a few servers and I want to ssh into each one, add that user and give him the password I took from my password file (Same user with same password on every servers) and so I'd like to run it from my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a script which will be changing the passwords and execute that in the remote machine like this:

Change your fist script:

```
#!/bin/bash
password=`cat /root/scripts/password`
for i in `cat /root/scripts/LIST_TEST.txt`
do
        printf "Serveur : $i \n"
        #Password is passed as $1 to the next script
        cat ./paschange.sh $passwd | ssh $i #Command to excecute the  script
        echo $password
done
```

And `paschange.sh` will be:

```
#!/bin/bash
adduser newuser
yes $1 | passwd newuser #Password is passed as $1
```

Note that this assumes:

1. You will create a user named: `'newuser`' with the same name in ALL servers
2. He will have the same password for all servers
3. You are using the same name to login yourself to all those servers to run the script, which the username you have on the computer you are currently executing this script.

Comment: Hi @Oth. Really glad to help ;) if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.